# Why does import .NET libgdx doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, import

When I try:

```
Gdx.net.openURI("my_url");
```

The `.net` seems to need an import, but whatever I import, in doesn't work.

What import should i use?

Comment: please add the import statements that you have so far